# Calling JavaScript functions from HTML

Tags: javascript

How do I execute a JS object's function property from an HTML link?
I have the following JS:

```
function Tester(elem) {
    this.elem = document.getElementById(elem);
}

Tester.prototype.show = function() {
    this.elem.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript: this.test();">test</a>';
};

Tester.prototype.test = function() {
    alert("a");
};  
​
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = new Tester("test");
    test.show();
</script>
```

When I click on the link that gets rendered, it cannot identify the `test()` function. How would I get it so when a user clicks on the link, the `test()` function is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way would be to create a DOM element and attach the event handler with JavaScript:

```
Tester.prototype.show = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
        self = this; // assign this to a variable we can access in the 
                     // event handler

    a.href = '#';
    a.innerHTML = 'test';
    a.onclick = function() {     
        self.test();
        return false; // to prevent the browser following the link
    };

    this.elem.appendChild(a);
};
```

Since the event handler forms a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), it has access to the variables defined in the outer function (`Tester.prototype.show`). Note that inside the event handler, `this` does not refer to your instance, but to the element the handler is bound to (in this case `a`). [MDN has a good description of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

[quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/) has some [great articles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) about event handling, the various ways you can bind event handlers, their advantages and disadvantages, differences in browsers and [how `this` behaves in event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

It's also certainly helpful to make yourself familiar with the [DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM).